# Not able to call my web service through Advanced Rest Client. getting 404.

Tags: web-services

My application named as AdPortalWebService having a class

```
package com.adportal.implementations;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.adportal.vo.LoginDetails;

/**
* @author sahbhard
*
*/
@Path("/validateLogin")
public class ValidateLoginCredentials {

@POST
@Path("/validate")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
//@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response validateLogin(LoginDetails loginDetails){

    String result;
    System.out.println(loginDetails.getUserName());
    if (loginDetails.getUserName() == "admin" && loginDetails.getPassword() == "admin"){
        result = "success";
        return Response.status(200).build();
    }
    else{
        result = "fail";
        return Response.status(200).build();
    }
 }

}
```

I am entering the following URL 'http://localhost:8080/com.adportal.implementations/rest/validateLogin' but getting 404 as reponse. In my tomcat this application got deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling the wrong url, it should be:

```
http://localhost:8080/AdPortalWebService/validateLogin/validate
```

Also if the `result = fail` you should not be returning a 200 response, change it to a 401 (unauthorised user/request):

```
else {
    result = "fail";
    return Response.status(401).build();
}
```